# How to fix very long logon times on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows-server-2016, login, dism, lag

I recently have very long login times on a Windows Server 2016 Datacenter VM.

The boot is super fast, but after I type in credentials, it takes about 60 min until I get to the desktop. The login screen keeps "Applying User Settings" in the meantime.

This happens only on ONE of many (30+) servers within the domain environment, so Group Policy can't be an issue.

Shortly after rebooting, this does not occur, but after a few minutes of runtime, the issue keeps reoccuring.

It is not userspecific.

It is not a RDSH server.

Windows is up to date.

Dism shows repairable components, but fails after 100% with error message "Error: 1734 - The array bounds are invalid."

Comment: Anything considerable in Administrative Events during this slow logon?

Comment: @Manu absolutely nothing.. which is very frustrating when you're trying to solve this thing.

Comment: disable any Autorin programs items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an answer, but the problem resolved itself for no apparend reason. There was no Windows Update, no changes to server, software or hardware - we just rebooted the server, like we already did a hundred time before. But now it works perfectly fine. I hate Windows.

Answer (score 1):

1. Corrupt profile - You should not see this on a server. Most common on laptops and shared lab computers due to incomplete shutdowns. You will know if this is the cause because you will log on and in the right hand corner see Temp profile used. To correct open regedit and Navigate to the following - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE >Software>Microsoft>Windows NT>CurrentVersion>ProfileList - locate the folder with a .bak extension and delete it.
2. KerbTicket issue - If you see the following message -   "The Trust relationship between this workstation and the Domain failed" For whatever reason your kerbos tickets for authentication are out of synch with the issuing authority on the Domain.

Regards,
John

Comment: Both not the case. 
Happens with all users logging in on that server. Even tried newly created.
Kerberos is fine too.